# How to properly echo colored text in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

Im having the following issue:

On bash I set:

```
COLOR="0;31" #red color
```

If I do

```
echo -e "\e[00;31mRED\e[00m"
```

I get

`RED` <- in red color on the terminal

However if I do

```
echo -e "\e[0$COLORm \RED\e[00m"
```

I just get

`RED` <- without colors

How can I print using color and my `$COLOR` variable?

Answer (score 1):

bash does not know anything about variable `COLORm`. But following example will work

```
COLOR="0;31m"
echo -e "\e[0$COLOR \RED\e[0m"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `${var}` – e.g. `\e[0;${COLOR}m` – to separate the variable name from the surrounding text.

Alternatively, use `printf "\e[0;%sm %s \e[m\n" "$COLOR" "RED"`

*(Side note: `\e[00;31m` is not necessary; `\e[0;31m` or just `\e[;31m` is fine. Same applies to `\e[00m`)*

Answer (score 0):

Use curly brackets to isolate the variable name and eliminate ambiguity in expressions where the variable names are adjecent to some literal characters (such as ${hello}world) or other tricky places:

[image]